# How to Display Song's Album Art from device storage using MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ART

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-contentresolver

I am trying to make a MusicPlayer App. I want to display the AlbumArt using Content Resolver.

Here is My ContentResolver used to fetch Songs Information.

```
 public void getSongList(){
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri , null , null , null , null);
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int albumart = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                int thisAlbumArt = musicCursor.getInt(albumart);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist , thisAlbumArt));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

And here is my Custom getView method used to display the Views (images and texts of song information) in a Listview.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //map to song layout
        LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate
                (R.layout.songviewer, parent, false);
        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        ImageView albumArtView = (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.albumArtSongs);
        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);
        //get title and artist strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        albumArtView.setImageResource(currSong.getAlbumArt());
        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }
```

Whenever I try to run the app, the app keeps getting crashed.

I just want to know how to display the correct songArt in respect to its song using ContentResolver and the code mentioned above.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please **STOP!!** reposting your question over and over again? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to get the album art from the external storage of the device and display it respective to their songs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811103/i-want-to-get-the-album-art-from-the-external-storage-of-the-device-and-display)

Comment: This is already the 3rd copy of your original post, today.